# Sequences convergence and neighbourhood, theorem

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

> Theorem: Let $\{x_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence in a metric space $(X,d)$, let $a$ be a point in $X$. Assume that $V(a)$ is the neighbourhood of $a$. The following conditions are equivalent:
>
> ($i$) $\forall p\in V(a),\forall N\in\mathbb{N},\exists n\geqslant N $ such that $x_n\in V$;
>
> ($ii$) $\forall p\in V(a)$ the set of positive integers $\{n\in\mathbb{N}\,;\,x_n\in V\}$ is infinite;
>
> ($iii$) The sequence $\{x_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ has a subsequence $\{x_{n_j}\}_{j\in\mathbb{N}}$ that converges to $a$.

Question:

**1)** Does ($i$),($ii$),($iii$) imply that $x_n$ converges to $a$?

**2)** When it is stated ($i$) $\forall p\in V(a),\forall N\in\mathbb{N},\exists n\geqslant N $ such that $x_n\in V$, does this imply that $x_n$ is in the neighbourhood of any point $a\in X$, or that $a$ must be the point of convergence?

**3)** I guess that the sequence can be in the neighbourhood of a point only if it converges to that point. Is this implied by the theorem?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, there is something wrong with your notation, which might be the (or one of the) case(es) why you are confused. I suppose that $V(a)$ is the *set of neighborhoods of $a$*, not just one particular neighborhood. Then (i) and (ii) should read as follows.

(i) $\forall\ \color{red}{V}\in V(a),\forall N\in\mathbb N,\exists n\geq N:\ x_n\in\color{red}V$.

(ii) $\forall\ \color{red}{V}\in V(a)$ the set $\{n\in\mathbb N: x_n\in \color{red}{V}\}$ is infinite.

This means that in each neighborhood *of $a$* there are *infinitely many* members of the sequence $(x_n)$ (but also infinitely many members can be outside).

Now, I'm answering your questions:

**(1)** No. For instance, the sequence $x_n=(-1)^n$ does not converge to $a=1$, but the subsequence $x_{2j}=1$ does.

**(2)** The point $a$ is fixed. See above.

**(3)** Convergence to $a$ means that in each neighborhood of $a$ there are *infinitely many* members of $(x_n)$ $\color{red}{\text{and only finitely many are outside}}$. Compare with (i) above.